# SharedPreferences Logical Error

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

This is my code:

```
package com.example.sharedprefs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void doThis (View view){
        i++;
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("userChoice",i);
        prefEditor.commit();
        int number = sharedPref.getInt("userChoice", 0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number + "" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.finish();

    }

}
```

When the app runs and I run it again. I constantly get "1" as a toast. I'm trying to get 1 and 2 and 3 and so on. Any ideas? I know that it's not the program, it's the "programmer" at this point. Thanks in advance

Comment: put `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);i = sharedPref.getInt("userChoice", 0);` to onCreate of Activity ... i is 0 every time you start this Activity

Comment: Yep, that worked. Post that as an answer if you'd like, so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer given in the first comment; [SharedPreferences Logical Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905741/sharedpreferences-logical-error#comment17482445_12905741).

You should put the following code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName",MODE_PRIVATE);
i = sharedPref.getInt("userChoice", 0);
```

in the `onCreate()`-method in your Activity.

In your code, i is 0 every time you start this Activity.